# Using PowerShell to move a matching set of files with same name but different extensions to two different destinations

Tags: powershell, directory, matching

I would like to use PowerShell to move a matching name set of files (1 job file and 1 trigger file both havening the same name just different extensions) from one directory to another.  See example below.

Source directory contains job1.zip, job1.trg, job2.zip, and job2.trg.  I would like to take matching job names job1.zip and job1.trg and move it to dest1folder, only if it is empty, if not move it to dest2folder.  Then loop back to perform the same logic for job2.zip and job2.trg.  One thing I also have to take into consideration is the Source directory may only contain job1.zip waiting for job1.trg to be transferred.  I am a newbie to PowerShell and blown hours on trying to get it working with no success.  Is it possible?

This is what I have so far.  I get the files to move to each destination folder using IF logic, but it moves all of the files in the source directory.

```
$doirun = (get-childItem "d:\ftproot\pstest\").Count

$filecount = (get-childItem "d:\ftproot\ps2\").Count

if ($doirun -le 1) {exit} 

$dir = get-childitem "d:\ftproot\pstest\" | Where-Object {($_.extension -eq ".zip") -or ($_.extension -eq ".trg")}

foreach ($file in $dir)
{
   if ($filecount -le 2) {Move-item "d:\ftproot\pstest\$file"  "d:\ftproot\ps2\"} 
   else {Move-item "d:\ftproot\pstest\$file" "d:\ftproot\ps3\"}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested extensively, but I believe this should work:

```
$jobs = gci d:\ftproot\pstest\* -include *.zip,*.trg |
  select -expand basename | sort -unique
$jobs |foreach-object {
 if (test-path d:\ftproot\pstest\$_.zip -and test-path d:\ftproot\pstest\$_.trg){
  if (test-path d:\ftproot\pstest\ps2\*){
    move-item d:\ftproot\pstest\$_.zip d:\ftproot\pstest\ps3
    move-item d:\ftproot\pstest\$_.trg d:\ftproot\pstest\ps3
    }
  else {
    move-item d:\ftproot\pstest\$_.zip d:\ftproot\pstest\ps2
    move-item d:\ftproot\pstest\$_.trg d:\ftproot\pstest\ps2
    }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks Mjolinor that works! I had to add a few parenthesis to the first test to get the “and” logic to work correctly.  “ if ((test-path d:\ftproot\pstest\$_.zip) -and (test-path d:\ftproot\pstest\$_.trg)){ “  Thank you for taking the time to help me out.